# Display functions like '+' or '[' as is

Tags: r, knitr

When I write code chunk in Rmd-file

````
```{r}
'+'(3,5)
```
````

`knitr` returns html-file as

```
3 + 5
```

So it transforms the expression to more common format. How can I disable such transformation to keep expression as is?
In comparison, the same code in Rpres-file is displayed correctly `'+'(3,5)`.

Comment: set `tidy = FALSE`

Comment: @rawr And it will be the default in the next version of knitr (currently on [Github](https://github.com/yihui/knitr)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the credit goes to @rawr, and his comment of "set `tidy = FALSE`".

This question needed an answer.

````
```{r, tidy=FALSE}
'+'(3, 5)
```
````

produces
[image]